# Android Email Intent - Received file attachment is Zero bytes

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

I setup an email intent in my app. I also attach a binary file with it. When the email editor opens up it shows how many bytes. But when I receive the email it is Zero Bytes!

I have done this on a separate project and it worked before so I just copied that code to the new project.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message here");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///data/data/com.example.app/files/filename.extension"));
```

I have tested it on Gingerbread and Jelly bean. I used the default email editor of the devices(Galaxy Y and HTC One).

Again the received attachment is Zero Bytes even if the email editor shows some bytes(i.e. 306 bytes)

-------UPDATE---------

So I created another project and tested the code below. It sends an email with attachment. But when I use the same code on my project the email received is zero byte. You can see I even tested if the file object is null and it is not null when ran.

```
File file = new File(File.getFilePath(context, "myfile.code"));
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Blah...blah...");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "File sent");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file)); //I also used file:///data/data/com.example.emailfile/files/myfile.code and didn't work

if(file == null){
Log.d("----FILE----", "NULL");
}else{
Log.d("----FILE----", "Not Null");
}
```

This is driving me crazy...any settings or setup I did on my project that prevents attachment?

Btw, the activity where this is running only has radio buttons and a button to invoke the email intent. I'm sending the email either using gmail or outlook.

Comment: Having said default email editor. You mean Gmail app?

Comment: the manufacturer default email editor. I tried it with Gmail and Outlook and none of them worked.

Comment: 'I have done this on a separate project and it worked before so I just copied that code to the new project' what do you mean by this statement? Was the same code working fine before you ported to another project?

Comment: If the same above code worked before for you then may be you have missed something else if it never worked for you then i can help you. Coz the way you attaching the file to email is quite suspicious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

First of course make sure the file is MODE_WORLD_READABLE.

Second Gmail seems to don't have access to internal storage or files within apps. Also, discussed here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18872

It managed to send and the attachment using outlook.